# Enable / Disabled button not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any reason why code below is not working for `enable/disable` a html button?. The function is called when a dropdown is change. As you can see I test 3 different codes. BTW I am using `jquery 1.5.1`

```
function EnableDisableBrowseDocs() {
    var x = $("#DocumentClassificationId").val();
    var Document201Id = $("#Document201Id").val();
    var curAction = $("#hidCurAction").val();
    if (x > 0 && Document201Id > 0 && curAction == "EditProfile") {
        //$("#btnUpload201Doc").attr("disabled", false);
        //document.getElementById("btnUpload201Doc").disabled = false;
        $("#btnUpload201Doc").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('#btnUpload201Doc').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        //$("#btnUpload201Doc").attr("disabled", true);
        //document.getElementById("btnUpload201Doc").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <input id="btnUpload201Doc" type="file" disabled="disabled" style="width: 0px; display:none" />
```

Comment: When you debug, what fails?  Are the variables what you expect them to be?  Does the `if` condition evaluate how you expect it to?  Do the jQuery selectors find what you expect them to?  Is the `disabled` attribute of that element modified?

Comment: What does “not working” mean? Please [edit] your question and describe _precisely_ how you expect your code to work and how exactly it fails to do that.

Comment: @Matt Edited Sorry.

Comment: @Xufox As you can see in the function the button must be Enable/Disable when the condition is meet.

Comment: @David when I debug I didn't encounter any error or fails. I don't know why the button is not Enable/Disable

Comment: Have you tried checking each value with `console.log`?

Comment: Whether or not the button is enabled or disabled, it has display:none it wouldn't be visible

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/2ekobLvo/

Comment: @AliRasheed That helps a lot.. Thanks I focus to much on the code but not checking on the ID's of the button that I used.

Comment: A bit of advice. Do CSS at the end bruh!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possibilities:

- The code is not reaching the actual button, in debug check whether it goes into the right branch, and the jQuery selector matches the right element
- Maybe it needs a property setting not an attribute setting. Maybe try `$("#btnUpload201Doc").prop('disabled', valueForDisabled);` instead.